# Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors different from linear regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima, forecasting

A Regression with ARIMA errors is given by the following formula (saw on Hyndman et al, 1998):

$Y_t = b_0 + b_1 X_{1,t} + \dots + b_k X_{k,t} + N_t$

where $N_t$ is modeled as an ARIMA process.

If we have that the model for $N_t$ is ARIMA$(0,0,0)$, then $N_t = e_t$, and $Y_t$ is modeled by an ordinary regression.

Suppose the following data:

```
a <- structure(c(29305, 9900, 9802, 17743, 49300, 17700, 24100, 11000, 
10625, 23644, 38011, 16404, 14900, 16300, 18700, 11814, 13934, 
12124, 18097, 30026, 3600, 15700, 12300, 14600), .Tsp = c(2010.25, 
2012.16666666667, 12), class = "ts")
b <- structure(c(1.108528016, 1.136920872, 1.100239002, 1.057191265, 
1.044200511, 1.102063834, 1.083847756, 1.068585841, 1.084879628, 
1.232979511, 1.168894672, 1.257302058, 1.264967051, 1.234793782, 
1.306452369, 1.252644047, 1.178593218, 1.124432965, 1.132878661, 
1.189926986, 1.17249669, 1.176285957, 1.176552, 1.179178082), .Tsp = 
c(2010.25, 2012.16666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

If I model it using `auto.arima` function, I have:

```
auto.arima(a, xreg=b)
Series: a 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
              b
      15639.266
s.e.   1773.186

sigma^2 estimated as 101878176:  log likelihood=-255.33
AIC=514.65   AICc=515.22   BIC=517.01

lm(a~b)

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b  
      48638       -26143
```

Coefficients from the models differ. Shouldn't they be the same? What am I missing?

Comment: your first (auto.arima) model doesn't have an intercept... try using a-mean(a) and b-mean(b) to eliminate the need for one. You'll get the same coefficient estimate that lm gives if you do.

Comment: Yes, if I remove the mean, the `auto.arima` model generates the same coefficients that `lm`. But why isn't it estimating an intercept when I use the raw data? Shouldn't the procedures be the same inside `auto.arima`?

Comment: If you just use `arima`, you can specify `include.mean=TRUE` in which case you'll get the `lm` coefficient estimate; I too find it a little odd that `auto.arima` doesn't allow this option (I just tested it) but I expect there's a good reason for it.

Comment: I believe it's because the purpose of `auto.arima` is automatically estimates all coefficients, including the choice of include or not the intercept.

So, it seems the results are different because the intercept is not being calculated in the "regression" part of the model, but in the ARIMA. And in this specific case, they disagree: (a) `lm` chooses to include an intercept and (b) ARIMA chooses not to include. Is it correct? EDIT: Actually it doesn't seem to be correct, because if the intercept is on the $N_t$ part, it's the same thing if it's on the regression when we substitute.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the difference between the models is that `auto.arima()` has not included an intercept. It selects a model, possibly including the constant, using the AICc. With one covariate, the model is
$$y_t = \beta_0 x_t + n_t$$
where $n_t$ is an ARIMA process. Note that the intercept is shifted to the ARIMA process. In this example, the selected model for $n_t$ does not include a constant.

If you know what model you want, why use `auto.arima()`? Instead, you could use

```
arima(a,xreg=b)
```

which gives

```
Series: a 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept          b
       48638.40  -26143.23
s.e.   32410.27   27893.41

sigma^2 estimated as 93138232:  log likelihood=-254.25
AIC=514.5   AICc=515.7   BIC=518.03
```

This is the same as the model obtained using `lm(a~b)`. The estimates are identical, but the standard errors are different because they are estimated in a different way (numerically from the hessian matrix rather than using the inverse of $(X'X)$.)