# Arima and lm not giving same coefficients in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, least-squares

I'm fitting an `arima`(1,0,0) model using the `forecast` package in R on the `usconsumption` dataset. However, when I mimic the same fit using `lm`, I get different coefficients. My understanding is that they should be the same (in fact, they give the same coefficients if I model an `arima`(0,0,0) and `lm` with only the external regressor, which is related to this post: [Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0) errors different from linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28472/regression-with-arima0-0-0-errors-different-from-linear-regression)).

Is this because `arima` and `lm` use different techniques to calculate coefficients? If so, can someone explain the difference?

Below is my code.

```
> library(forecast)
> library(fpp)
> 
> #load data
> data("usconsumption")
> 
> #create equivalent data frame from time-series
> lagpad <- function(x, k=1) {
+   c(rep(NA, k), x)[1 : length(x)] 
+ }
> usconsumpdf <- as.data.frame(usconsumption)
> usconsumpdf$consumptionLag1 <- lagpad(usconsumpdf$consumption)
> 
> #create arima model
> arima(usconsumption[,1], xreg=usconsumption[,2], order=c(1,0,0))

Call:
arima(x = usconsumption[, 1], order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = usconsumption[, 2])

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept  usconsumption[, 2]
      0.2139     0.5867              0.2292
s.e.  0.0928     0.0755              0.0605

sigma^2 estimated as 0.3776:  log likelihood = -152.87,  aic = 313.74
> 
> #create lm model
> lm(consumption~consumptionLag1+income, data=usconsumpdf)

Call:
lm(formula = consumption ~ consumptionLag1 + income, data = usconsumpdf)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  consumptionLag1           income  
         0.3779           0.2456           0.2614
```

Comment: where income in your arima? your models are not the same in lm and arima

Comment: Income is `usconsumption[,2]` in arima.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating a little on @Richard's answer:

The model 
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \gamma_0 + \gamma_2 x_t + u_t, \\
u_t &= \varphi_1 u_{t-1} + v_t.
\end{aligned}
$$
can be rearranged from noting that $u_{t} = y_t-\gamma_0 - \gamma_2 x_{t}$ so that $u_{t-1} = y_{t-1}-\gamma_0 - \gamma_2 x_{t-1}$. Plugging this into the equation for $u_t$ gives
$$
y_t-\gamma_0 - \gamma_2 x_{t}=\varphi_1(y_{t-1}-\gamma_0 - \gamma_2 x_{t-1})+v_t
$$
or
$$
y_t =\gamma_0(1-\varphi_1)+\gamma_2 x_{t}+\varphi_1y_{t-1} - \varphi_1\gamma_2 x_{t-1}+v_t
$$
Hence, the second model has a nonlinear coefficient restriction on the coefficient of the constant and, more importantly, also implicitly includes $x_{t-1}$.

Let us generate some data from the second model and estimate the restricted arima as well as unrestricted OLS model including $x_{t-1}$:

```
n <- 5000
x <- rnorm(n)
u <- arima.sim(list(ar=0.5),n=n)
gamma_0 <- 1
gamma_2 <- 2
y <- gamma_0 + gamma_2*x + u
```

The results are

```
> arima(y, xreg=x, order=c(1,0,0))

Call:
arima(x = y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = x)

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept       x
      0.4880     1.0196  2.0135
s.e.  0.0123     0.0279  0.0128
```

and

```
> lm(y[2:n]~x[2:n]+y[1:(n-1)]+x[1:(n-1)])

Call:
lm(formula = y[2:n] ~ x[2:n] + y[1:(n - 1)] + x[1:(n - 1)])

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)        x[2:n]  y[1:(n - 1)]  x[1:(n - 1)]  
      0.5222        2.0164        0.4880       -0.9771
```

We see that, for example, the coefficient on $x_{t-1}$, $-0.9771$ is close to the one implied by the restricted arima model $-0.4880\cdot2.0135=-0.983$. Also, as predicted, the coefficients on $x_t$ are close in both models, and so are those on $u_{t-1}$ and $y_{t-1}$. (I suspect remaining differences to be due to different underlying algorithms in `arima` and `lm`.)

Comment: Thanks for the details, Christoph! This explanation really helps!

Answer (score 3):

With `lm(consumption~consumptionLag1+income, data=usconsumpdf)` you are fitting

$$ y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \beta_2 x_t + \varepsilon_t. $$

With `arima(x = usconsumption[, 1], order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = usconsumption[, 2])` you are fitting

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \gamma_0 + \gamma_2 x_t + u_t, \\
u_t &= \varphi_1 u_{t-1} + v_t.
\end{aligned}
$$

This is not the same model; $\beta_0 \neq \gamma_0$, $\beta_2 \neq \gamma_2$, and $\beta_1 \neq \varphi_1$ in general. No wonder then that you find $\hat\beta_0 \neq \hat\gamma_0$, $\hat\beta_2 \neq \hat\gamma_2$, or $\hat\beta_1 \neq \hat\varphi_1$.

<del>(Also, why do you use different variable names in the two models, e.g. `consumption` in `lm` but `usconsumption[, 1]` in `arima`? Or if the variables are actually different, then why would you expect the two models to give the same result?)</del>

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I think I get it now. As for `consumption` and `usconsumption`, I had just named things differently when creating a data frame. They are the same thing.