# R ARIMA implementation

Tags: r, estimation, arima

I am wondering how R implement the ARIMA model. So the function `arima` with order (1,0,0) should be the same as AR(1) model. However when I run it, the estimated coefficients are different than my Excel and Python (Statsmodels) tests. By the way, Excel and Statsmodels output the same coefficients.

$$
y_t = \alpha+ \beta \cdot y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$

When I was searching, I noticed the question in the link below. And my understanding from these answers is that the `arima` function of R is not estimating the above model but rather the one below. I omitted the exogenous variables here.

$$
y_t = \gamma_0 + u_t \\
u_t = \delta u_{t-1} + v_t
$$

[Arima and lm not giving same coefficients in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223379/arima-and-lm-not-giving-same-coefficients-in-r)

So the question is, which model does R run with the `arima` function with order (1,0,0) and no exogenous variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As stated in the documentation, `stats::arima` uses the regression-with-ARIMA-errors parametrization uniformly for all models (including where the only "exogenous" variable is a constant), which is the second set of equations you show. Other packages sometimes treat the constant vs not constant exogenous case in inconsistent parametrizations, or have misleading documentation that claims ARIMAX in one place and regression-with-ARIMA-errors in the other. If I recall correctly, statsmodels has both issues.

Comment: Also stated in the documentation is that `stats::arima` uses maximum likelihood estimation by default, not least squares. They give different estimates.

Comment: hi: besides the good points that chris and rob raised, the estimation methodology is tricky because of the issue of initialization. So, the estimation algorithm is going to have to deal with initializing which adds another layer where differences ( between statsmodels-python versus R )  could occur.