# Different ways to do autoregression in R

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, method-comparison

Can someone explain why different ways of doing autoregression give different estimates?  For example, I can use regression with a lag, or I can use arima(), or gls() in package nlme:

```
x <- 1:100
e <- 25*arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.3),n=100)
y <- 1 + 2*x + e

# 1st way:
y.lm <- lm(y[-1] ~ y[-length(y)] + x[-1])
summary(y.lm)               

# 2nd way:
arima(y, xreg=x, order=c(1,0,0))    

# 3rd way:
library(nlme)
y.gls <- gls(y ~ x, corr=corAR1())
summary(y.gls)
```

In my experiments, the first two give the best estimates for the autocorrelation coefficient while the Phi estimate in the 3rd is too high. And perhaps more importantly, the coefficient for x is about right in both the arima() and gls() outputs, but too small with the lm() approach. So arima() seems most reliable - but what's wrong with my lm() approach, and what is gls() doing?

(I realise that a partial answer has been given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223392/365775 - but that answer fits my understanding of a moving-average model (order(0,0,1) in arima) rather than a AR model... maybe I need to start a separate thread on that. But it doesn't explain the gls() differences.)

Comment: What is `x` here? If you expressed that and set a seed for reproducibility, you could also show the results

Comment: 1st and 2nd seem different to me; see https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/ on how to interpret the underlying model of the `arima` function. (I don't know what 3rd is.)

Comment: @Henry - Sorry - now edited to show the creation of x.

Comment: @Richard Hardy - thanks for that link to a helpful explanation about ARIMA vs ARIMAX.

Comment: @RichardG, you are welcome!